# r: Unite dataframe columns in pairs

Tags: r

I want to know how I can programatically join columns together in pairs.  I'm looking for a general solution that could work for different numbers of columns.

for example, if I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
Id column1 column2 column3 column4 column5 column6
 3       0      50       0      51       0      54
 5       1      24       3      56       1      26
 6       5       7       5       8       5       3
```

I want to unite the columns in the series, such that column1 and column2 are united, column3 and column4 are united and column 5 and column 6 are united, like this:

```
Id column1&2 column3&4 column5&6
 3      0,50      0,51      0,54
 5      1,24      3,56      1,26
 6       5,7       5,8       5,3
```

reproducible data:

```
structure(list(Id = c(3L, 5L, 6L), column1 = c(0L, 1L, 5L), column2 = c(50L, 
24L, 7L), column3 = c(0L, 3L, 5L), column4 = c(51L, 56L, 8L), 
column5 = c(0L, 1L, 5L), column6 = c(54L, 26L, 3L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: shuld the be united to a character string or a list/vector??

Comment: If you want a character vector, there is https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/unite.html . However, the `tidyverse` is quite a large library to load for a single function call. If that is of concern to you, someone else might suggest a leaner solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple option in base R, is to iterate over every second index and combine the columns using `paste`.

```
# import data
df <- read.table(header = TRUE, 
text = "Id column1 column2 column3 column4 column5 column6
 3       0      50       0      51       0      54
 5       1      24       3      56       1      26
 6       5       7       5       8       5       3")
# Index to iterate over every second column
index <- seq.int(2, ncol(df), 2) 
# Create new columns (split data frame, convert to vectors, combine vectors across using `paste(v1, v2, sep = ',')`. 
newcols <- lapply(index, function(i)
    paste(df[[i]], df[[i + 1]], sep = ','))
# Actually create the columns, and convert to a `data.frame`. Combine using `do.call(cbind, ...)`. Add our Id from the original data.
df_new <- cbind(Id = df$Id, as.data.frame(do.call(cbind, newcols)))
# Generate names. Once again use `paste(v1, v2)` to paste across 
new_names <- paste0('column', paste0(index, '&', index + 1))
# Set names to non-id columns
names(df_new)[-1] <- new_names
# Print result
df_new

#  Id column2&3 column4&5 column6&7
#1  3      0,50      0,51      0,54
#2  5      1,24      3,56      1,26
#3  6       5,7       5,8       5,3
```

**Explanation:**
Notice that

```
paste(c(1,2), c(2,3))
# out
c("1 2", "2 3")
```

Knowing this, my basic idea is to subset the columns iteratively (2+3, 4+5 and 6+7), convert the 2 columns to vector pairs, and then call `paste` with `sep = ','`. The trick becomes converting our data to the appropriate input for this process.

Comment: This did not give me the output you're showing, but just the last column combined

Comment: It seems the errors comes from me storing the data as a `data.table` rather than `data.frame`. I'll update the answer shortly, to fix these. Also the single column should come from me setting `x` rather than `i` as the function input, and then using `i` to subset the data. So you might have a variable `i` stored. Anyway, i'll fix it in a moment.

Comment: @Niamh45, the errors should be fixed and the data has been added to ensure reproducibility.

Answer (score 1):

Since you haven't (yet) given an answer to the question what type the combined columns should have here are both solutions in base R:

Use `paste` to create strings:

```
testdata$column1and2_STRING <- paste(testdata$column1, testdata$column2, sep=", ")
```

Using `mapply` to create lists:

```
testdata$column1and2_LIST <- mapply(FUN=c, testdata$column1, testdata$column2, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
```

The output will look the same, but the type of the columns (and what we can do with them) is different...

```
testdata
```

Is now:

> ```
>   Id column1 column2 column3 column4 column5 column6 column1and2_STRING column1and2_LIST
> 1  3       0      50       0      51       0      54              0, 50            0, 50
> 2  5       1       4       3      56       1      26               1, 4             1, 4
> 3  6       5       7       5       8       5       3               5, 7             5, 7
> ```

See also:

```
str(testdata)
```

> ```
> 'data.frame': 3 obs. of  9 variables:
> $ Id                : int  3 5 6
> $ column1           : int  0 1 5
> $ column2           : int  50 4 7
> $ column3           : int  0 3 5
> $ column4           : int  51 56 8
> $ column5           : int  0 1 5
> $ column6           : int  54 26 3
> $ column1and2_STRING: chr  "0, 50" "1, 4" "5, 7"
> $ column1and2_LIST  :List of 3
>   ..$ : int  0 50
>   ..$ : int  1 4
>   ..$ : int  5 7
> ```